# Checkbox Form Submit via Jquery-Ajax

Tags: forms, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to submit the form when a checkbox is checked via jQuery ajax. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a user friendly, but you can do it by this

```
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    // Is checkbox checked?
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // Send parent form data via post
        $.post('submission-url.html', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(data) {
            // process response
        });
    }
});
```

You can get `action` attribute from `form` element by `$(this).closest('form').attr('action')` instead of 'submission-url.html'